# Can we create drop down list with check box option using epplus library

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-web-api, epplus

Initialize the worksheet:

```
public HttpResponseMessage ER_GenerateWBLWorksheet2()
    {
ExcelPackage ExclPkg = new ExcelPackage();
 ExcelWorksheet wsSheet1 = ExclPkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
  wsSheet1.Cells["A1"].Value = "ProductName";
            wsSheet1.Cells["B1"].Value = "Price";
            wsSheet1.Cells["C1"].Value = "ProductImageUrl";
            wsSheet1.Cells["D1"].Value = "ProductUrl";
            wsSheet1.Cells["E1"].Value = "StoreId";
            wsSheet1.Cells["G1"].Value = "CategoryId";
            wsSheet1.Cells["I1"].Value = "ColorId";
            wsSheet1.Cells["K1"].Value = "FabricId";
            wsSheet1.Cells["M1"].Value = "Gender";
```

Create Category list:

```
var categorylist = wsSheet1.DataValidations.AddListValidation(wsSheet1.Cells["G2:G500"].Address);
                var categories = _categoryServices.GetAllCategory();
                var categoryEntities = (categories != null) ? categories.ToList() : new List<CategoryEntity>();
                for (int i = 0; i < categoryEntities.Count; i++)
                {
                    categorylist.Formula.Values.Add(categoryEntities[i].CategoryName.ToString());

                }
            categorylist.ShowErrorMessage = true;
            categorylist.ErrorTitle = "Error";
            categorylist.Error = "Please select the Category from Dropdown";
            wsSheet1.Cells["G2:G500"].Style.Locked = false;
```

Create color list:

```
            var colorlist = wsSheet1.DataValidations.AddListValidation(wsSheet1.Cells["I2:I500"].Address);
            var colors = _colorServices.GetAllColor();
            var colorsEntities = (colors != null) ? colors.ToList() : new List<ColorEntity>();
            for (int i = 0; i < colorsEntities.Count; i++)
            {
                colorlist.Formula.Values.Add(colorsEntities[i].ColorName.ToString());
            }
            colorlist.ShowErrorMessage = true;
            colorlist.ErrorTitle = "Error";
            colorlist.Error = "Please select the Color from Dropdown";
            wsSheet1.Cells["I2:I500"].Style.Locked = false;
 wsSheet1.Cells[wsSheet1.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
            var filename = @"Inventory_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M_dd_yyyy_H_M_s") + ".xlsx";
            //string sPath = @"e:\" + filename;

           var sPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/exportedfiles/" + filename);

            Stream stream = File.Create(sPath);
            ExclPkg.SaveAs(stream);
            stream.Close();
            string strServerPath = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["excelserverpath"]);
            var sPathURL = (strServerPath + "exportedfiles/" + filename);
            List<fileinfo> filelst = new List<fileinfo>();
            fileinfo file = new fileinfo();
            file.filename = filename;
            file.fileurl = sPathURL;
           //file.fileurl = sPath;
            filelst.Add(file);
            return new ResponseWrapper<fileinfo>(filelst, HttpStatusCode.OK, null, 0);

        }
```

Using the above code I have created excel with drop down list, but my requirement is to select multiple values from drop down list. Is it possible using epplus library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a dropdownlist of checkboxes using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050195/create-a-dropdownlist-of-checkboxes-using-epplus)